# Same API request, two different responses from two different browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-api, chromium, google-vision

I have a DjangoREST/Vue.js application. In it, a user has to upload a picture and then, it's analyzed by the Google Vision API.
My issue is I have two differnt response from the same app in two different browsers:

Response from : `Chromium Version 78.0.3904.108 (Build officiel) Built on Raspbian , running on Raspbian 10 (32 bits)`

[image: chromium response]

Response from : `Google Chrome Version 86.0.4240.77(Build officiel)(64bits)`

[image: Chrome API]

Is it because of the chrome version? Or because I run Chrome on a Chromebook and Chromium on Raspbian?

I've updated to Chromium 84 and get the same response that with Chrome now. But if I pass the picture into: `https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop` I have the same labels as in Chromium.